# Limit of $x_n=0,\!7777...7$ ($n$ is the number of digits $7$)

Tags: limits

I have a sequence $n$-th member of which equals to $x_n=0,\!777...7$ (where $n$ is a number of digits $7$).

I've successfully proven that this is a Cauchy sequence. That means it converges to a limit. My question is, what is the limit?

I thought that it could be $0,\!78$, but the difference $0,\!78-x_n \ge 0,\!0022$.

Comment: It is $\frac79$!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Write $x_n$ as a geometric series (a sum of $7$ times powers of $10$), and use the formula for a geometric series.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without explicitly summing a geometric series, by noting that from $x_n$ to $x_{n+1}$ we are just setting the $n+1$th digit of the answer from $0$ to $7$. If you think of it as building up the number $x$, we have that $x_m$ sets the $m$th digit as $7$ and doesn't alter any previous or subsequent digits. The limit is therefore $0.777\dots$

Once you've got that, you can note that $0.999\dots = 1$ (indeed, their difference is smaller than $0.00\dots1$ for any number of $0$s) and so $0.111\dots = \frac{1}{9}$, so $0.777\dots = \frac{7}{9}$.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{7}{10^n}=\frac{7}{9} \ne 0,78$